# Separate eclipse plugin.xml for SWTBot test

Tags: eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin, swtbot

I have some plugin UI tests running using SWTBot.
As a result of this i had to add some libraries for SWTBot and some other things to the dependencies and classpath of the plugin.xml. But i dont want to have these in the software delivery.

Is there a way to set up a second plugin.xml just for the tests or any other solution to separate this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate plugin to hold your tests and SWTBot dependencies.

Comment: But how do i handle the inconsistencies between the two plugin projects?

Comment: You are going to have to explain what you mean by inconsistencies. Typically, the test plugin depends on the product plugin and uses classes located in the product plugin.